# What is the interval of W(A)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let *A* be the following matrix:
\begin{equation*} A= \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \end{equation*}
If the set *W*(A) is defined by:

*W*(*A*) = { (*A*u|u) : u ∈ $\mathbb{R^2}$ , ||u|| = 1 } where (*A*u|u) is the dot product.

The set *W*(*A*) is in an interval. Find that interval.

I have found the eigenvalues of *A* but I don't know how to continue from there

Comment: What do you mean the interval?

Comment: The set W(A) is in an interval, with a maximum and minimum value. The answer is supposed to be an interval between the eigenvalues but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to get that.

Comment: Well you can find the eigenvalues by solving $\det(A - \lambda I) = 0$. Did you calculate those already?

Comment: @Gregory The question states "I have found the eigenvalues"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sketch of solution:** Let $Q$ denote the orthogonal matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of $A$. Note that $D = Q^TAQ$ is diagonal; moreover, we'll say that
$$
D = \pmatrix{\lambda_1 & 0\\0 & \lambda_2}.
$$
Show that $(Au|u) = (D(Q^Tu)|Q^Tu)$. Using this, conclude that $W(A) = W(D)$. In order to find $W(D)$, express $(Du|u)$ in terms of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ and the entries of $u$.

Comment: I'm not quite following the first equality with Au|u and DQtu|Qtu. How did you get that?

Comment: @SobhanDar I would suggest that you try to figure that out yourself first. As a hint, begin with the substitution $A = QDQ^T$.

Comment: I understand the simplification now. But is the reason why W(A)=W(D) because Q is orthogonal and ||Qtu||=1?

Comment: @SobhanDar Essentially yes, but I wouldn't call this a complete argument

Comment: Well because ||Qtu||=1 and Qtu is a member of $\mathbb{R^2}$ it satisfies all the conditions and thus W(A)=W(D) should be correct to say?

Comment: It is also important to note that for **every** $x \in \Bbb R^2$ with $\|x\| = 1$, there exists a $u$ such that $Q^Tu = x$. Otherwise, we would only be able to say that $W(A) \subset W(D)$.

Answer (score 3):

Since $A$ is real and symmetric, it can be orthogonally diagonalized by the spectral theorem: $A=PDP^T$ where $PP^T=I,D=\text{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2).$

Convince yourself that for any unit vector $u$, we have $\|P^Tu\|^2=(P^Tu)^T(P^Tu)=1.$

Then convince yourself $(Au|u)=u^TAu=\sum_i \lambda_i (P^Tu)_i^2\in [\lambda_{\text{min}}\|P^Tu\|^2,\lambda_{\text{max}}\|P^Tu\|^2]=[\lambda_{\text{min}},\lambda_{\text{max}}].$

Comment: How do you go from $(P^Tu)^T(DP^Tu)$ to the sum that you wrote?

Comment: For any column vector $v=(v_1,...,v_n)^T$ and diagonal matrix $D=\text{diag}(D_1,...,D_n)$, you have $v^TDv=\sum_{i=1}^n D_iv_i^2.$ Write it out to convince yourself this is true.